# Ionic 4 with Angular Router

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am facing one issue related to routing, I have parent routing where I want to load few data which is common to all child routes. When I start the application I see the URL is changing in the browser, but it's not actually going to the Child component which is `ExamlistingPage`.

Here is AppRoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from ‘@angular/core’;
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from ‘@angular/router’;

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: ‘’, redirectTo: ‘testseries’, pathMatch: ‘full’ },
{
  path: 'login',
  loadChildren: () => import('./Page/login/login.module').then( m => 
  m.LoginPageModule)
},
{
  path: 'course',
  loadChildren: () => import('./Page/course/course.module').then( m => 
  m.CoursePageModule)
},
{
  path: 'testseries',
  loadChildren: () => import('./Page/test/test.module').then( m => 
  m.TestPageModule)
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

It's navigating to `testseries` and it's loading file in `testseries` component I am loading few data which is required for all child routes

```
import { NgModule } from ‘@angular/core’;
import { Routes, RouterModule } from ‘@angular/router’;
import { TestPage } from ‘./test.page’;

const routes: Routes = [
{
path: 'exams',
component: TestPage,
children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'examlisting', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'examlisting',
    loadChildren: () => import('./examlisting/examlisting.module').then(m => m.ExamlistingPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'testlisting',
    loadChildren: () => import('../../Page/test/testlisting/testlisting.module').then(m => m.TestlistingPageModule)
  }
]
},

// {
// path: ‘’,
// redirectTo: ‘/testseries/exams/examlisting’,
// pathMatch: ‘full’
// }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TestPageRoutingModule { }
```

in the browser I am seeing the URL is getting changed to http://localhost:/testseries/exams/examlisting but it is not loading `examlisting` component. Can someone help me see what mistake I am making?

Comment: Please indent your code, at the moment it is hardly readable.

Comment: You should tag this question as Angular as well.